# How to store array of Python dicts in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql

I have a Django project and such array in it:

```
{(0,0):{'a':True,'b':False ... },(0,1):{'a':True,'b':True ... },(1,1):{'a':True,'b':False ... }... }
```

I need to store this array in PostgreSQL database. I thought the ArrayField
could help, but I just have no idea how to declare such array.
I've read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/
but there was not my situation.
Could you show me an example?

I'm using Django 1.8

Comment: Yes you can JSON fields, also make sure that your postgres version should be 9.4 or higher, that only supports json field.

Answer (score 1):

JSON field should be perfect for you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class ModelName(models.Model):
    json_data = JSONField()
```

Now to save the data,

```
ModelName.objects.create(json_data={(0,0):{'a':True,'b':False ... },(0,1):{'a':True,'b':True ... },(1,1):{'a':True,'b':False ... }... })
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has two types you may want to check out,

- [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)
- [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

Both have overlapping functionality. JSON is part of the SQL 2016 spec though; hstore while having *some* advantages on JSONB is a PostgreSQL thing

Comment: Looks like i should use newer version of Django to solve my problem